# Prove that if $A, B $ are two sub-groups of $G$, and $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$ then $A \cap B = ${${e_G}$}

Tags: group-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I need some perspective to know if my solution is correct.

I suppose there exist $a \neq e \in A \cap B$, then $a^{|A|}=e $ and $a^{|B|}=e $.

Considering that $|A| \neq 1$ and $|B| \neq 1$ (otherwise it's obvious), then $gcd(|A|,|B|)\neq 1$ $\longrightarrow$ contradiction.

What do you say?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on "$\to$ contradiction". Bezout, perhaps? -- Also, this works as directproof

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You need to state that if $a^{|A|}=e$ and $a^{|B|}=e$, then $a^{\gcd(|A|,|B|}=e$.  Since $a\not=e$, $a^1\not=e$, so $\gcd(|A|,|B|)\not=1$.  This gives you the contradiction.

Comment: There is no need for contradiction in this proof.  You're actually wrapping a direct proof inside a contradiction.  Don't get me wrong, contradiction works, but it's not the most elegant approach.

Comment: Thank you, I just feel a bit unused to these stuff, I believe it will change as i practice...

Answer (score 3):

From $|A|\neq1\wedge|B|\neq1$ it cannot be concluded that $\gcd(|A|,|B|)\neq1$.
For instance take $|A|=2$ and $|B|=3$

Contradiction is not necessary.

If $a\in A\cap B$ then $a$ has an order that divides $|A|$ and $|B|$, hence divides $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$.

So $a$ must have order $1$ and consequently $a=e$.

Proved is now that $A\cap B=\{e\}$.

(not $A\cap B=e$ as you write).

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in a comment, it's simpler to do this proof as a direct proof instead of a contradiction.  Here's how it would go:

Suppose that $g\in A\cap B$.  Then, $g\in A$ and $g\in B$.  By Lagrange, $o(g)\mid|A|$ and $o(g)\mid|B|$.  Therefore, $o(g)|\gcd(|A|,|B|)$.  Since $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$, $o(g)\mid 1$.  Therefore, $o(g)=1$ and so $g^1=e$.  Therefore, $g=e$.  Hence $A\cap B=\{e\}$.